# Generalized linear model for Levy distribution with not complete data

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, levy-distribution

I'm trying to build a model that would describe some process of payment and distribution of payments in time. I believe that time of payment has [Levy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution) with probability density function:

$ f(x,c)=\sqrt{\frac{c}{2\pi}}~~\frac{e^{ -\frac{c}{2x}}} {x^{3/2}} $

This distribution depends on parameter *c* which actually defines the shape of distribution. My task is to build model that explains dependency of this parameter on some explaining variables. I'm trying linear dependency $c = \sum_i \beta_i x_i$

This is example of generalized linear model and is implemented in the [VGAM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) in R. Problem is that in a sample for building this model I have data only from some period at the beginning and this period is different for different groups of cases. And because of that I can not just to run the model in VGAM package on this data as the result will be incorrect significantly exaggerating probability of early payments.

One possible solution I can think about is to change the likelihood function from which parameter is estimated. If we have information only from time up to *t* and as cumulative distribution function of Levy distribution is:

$ F(x,c)=\textrm{erfc}\left(\sqrt{c/2x}\right) $

the density of distribution up to time *t*  is  $ f_1(x,c,t)= \frac{f(x,c)}{F(t,c)} $ (where $f(x,c), F(t,c)$ defined as above). This new density functions can be used in estimating regression parameters with maximum likelyhood method. But can it be done in R using methods from VGAM package or usual **glm** function or some other packages? Or there are some better approaches to my problem? I'm interested in implementation in R.